# Converting node to object

Tags: java, json, neo4j, neo4j-ogm, jooby

What is the proper way to convert `StatementResult` of Neo4j `session` execution to a proper object or at least a Json assuming I don't have access to `SessionFactory` ?

I am doing it like this and it looks clumsy and verbose:

```
var session = require(Driver.class).session(); // v1 Driver, v1 Session
try (session) {
    Iterable<Record> iterable =
            () -> session.run(FIND_BY_TITLE_LIKE, Map.of("titleLike", ".*" + titleLike + ".*"));
    var list = StreamSupport
            .stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
            .map(Record::asMap)
            .map(Map::values)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream) // nodes
            .map(node -> ((InternalNode) node).asMap())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    LOGGER.info("Processed list: {}", list);
    return list;
}
```

Maybe I should some other `Driver` or `Session` for that?

Comment: And why not using Neo4j-OGM ? It's the goal this project ... Otherwise you can write a function that convert a `Record` to `JSON` (or whatever) and put it in the first `Map` function (remove all the thing after)

Comment: @logisima ok, I'll try

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring-Data-Neo4j (SDN) to map query results to domain entities. You just need the following three code snippets.

### Repository

```
@Repository
public interface NodeEntityNameDAO extends Neo4jRepository<NodeEntityName, Long> {
  @Query("MATCH (nodeA:LabelA)<-[:CONTAINS]-(nodeB:LabelB) RETURN nodeA.name AS nodeAName, nodeB.name AS nodeBName;")
  NodeAAndBResult[] getNodeAAndB();
}
```

### Result object

```
@QueryResult
public class NodeAAndBResult {
  private String nodeAName;
  private String nodeBName;

  // omitted default constructor as well getter and setter for clarity
}
```

### Business logic

```
NodeAAndBResult[] nodeAAndBResults = nodeEntityNameDAO.getNodeAAndB();
```

---

### Addendum

Just found a [wonderful article](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/04/06/mapping-query-entities-sdn.html) by @Luanne from GraphAware for the same topic.

Comment: The thing is that...I don't use Spring